# Firebase Unity SDK MessageReceived

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Unity SDK 1.1.0 for messaging on Android. I added listeners for TokenReceived and MessageReceived in the Start method of a game object, like stated in the quick start tutorial:

```
void Start() {
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
}
```

This works without problems as long as the app is in foreground. When the app is sent to background, messages are sent to the notification tray, and when I tap on the notification my app is brought back to foreground. So everything is working as expected till this point. But after that the MessageReceived listener is not called any more. I tried removing both listeners in OnApplicationPause and adding them again when the application resumes:

```
void OnApplicationPause(bool paused) {
    if (paused) {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived -= OnTokenReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived -= OnMessageReceived;
    } else {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    }
}
```

But that did not help. I also tried pure notification messages without any data, but it's the same behaviour. Am I doing something wrong or Firebase Unity SDK is still in beta?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I could put this in the comments, but pictures cannot be included, so I enclosed that in an answer.

The code is correct and I can receive a message when the app is active, in background or even not started. Here is the snapshot.
[image]

Here is the full code:

```
public void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Unity Firebase App started");
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
}

public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token)
{
    Debug.Log("Received Registration Token: " + token.Token);
}

public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.From);
}
```

Comment: And OnMessageReceived gets still called after the app was paused and brought back to foreground by tapping on the notification entry (the "UnityFirebase / stack overflow" entry)?

Comment: I did not add your void OnApplicationPause(bool paused) {} in my project. and so it worked as described above.

Comment: The behaviour described happens with and without the additional code in OnApplicationPause. Also, it happens on different devices (Oneplus 3 with Android 7.0, Samsung S5 with Android 5.1.1)

Comment: I am getting problem in this. When I run game on unity editor, the listeners doesn't get called. I just need registrationToken for push notification send by GameSparks.